# Проблемы со стилями css

Tags: html, css

Сделал меню с помощью `ul`, завернул его в `header`, `header` покрасил в отдельный цвет. Почему-то `header` не на всю ширину заполняет окно браузера, остаются просветы фона в несколько пикселей по сторонам. Как избавиться от этих просветов?

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0
}

Comment: используйте reset.css  или normalize.css

Answer (score 1):

Каждый браузер имеет свои значения у `padding` и `margin`.
Поэтому многие используют такие вещи как `css reset`. Попробуй сделать

```
* {
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Но тогда потребуется проставлять у нужных блоков нужные отступы. Это называется контроль верстки

Answer (score 0):

```
margin 0 auto; // auto для центровки header-а
padding 0;
```